# How to fix this error 'Import In body of module; reorder to top import/first'?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, react-bootstrap

When install Bootstrap and jQuery in React, this happens.

(Using Linux deepin)

```
global.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import './index.css';
```

Comment: ok sure bro. But still can't vote. i will do :) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the `import` lines to the top of the file, before the require.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the eslint rule for this particular file with the below line -

```
/* eslint-disable import/first */
```

ref - [issue](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/4815#issuecomment-468352635)